# How to add variable to .py file from variable explorer

Tags: variables, spyder

New to Spyder IDE. If I use the variable explorer to import data from a .csv file and create a variable (numpy array), is there a simple way to add this variable to the .py file I'm coding in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) There's no way to do what you're asking for in Spyder, sorry.

Comment: bummer, but thanks Carlos!